# How to Upload File from angular7 to Node.js server

Tags: node.js, angular

My node.js code is working 100% by Postman,
but in angular when I send a `FormData` and nothing happened in server, no error but the file not uploaded.
how can i upload file by angular?

HTML Compnent:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" (change)="OnFileSelected($event)" name='photo'>
  <button type='submit' (click)="OnUpload()">Save Post</button>
</form>
```

Ts Compnent:

```
OnFileSelected(event){
  this.SelectedFile = event.target.files[0] as File;
}
OnUpload(){
  const form: FormData = new FormData();
  form.append('photo', this.SelectedFile, this.SelectedFile.name);
  //Convert to Json because 'Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse' error in server
  let responseBody: {} = JSON.stringify(form);
  this.http.post(URL, responseBody).subscribe(event => { console.log(event)}, err => {console.log(err)
    });
  }
```

Node.js Server:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const router = express.Router();
const DIR = './uploads';
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, DIR);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});
let upload = multer({ storage: storage });
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
router.post('/upload-image', upload.single('photo'),  async function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  if (!req.file) {
    console.log("No file received");
    return res.send({
      success: false
    });
  } else { 
    console.log('file: ',req.file);
    return res.send({
      success: true
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: let responseBody: {} = JSON.stringify(form); in here JSON.stringify is not required. send direct the form data into post request.

Comment: et responseBody: {} = JSON.stringify(form);...because 'Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse' error in server

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that your Request is a form-data request:

```
// Create Form Data
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('photo', this.SelectedFile, this.SelectedFile.name);

// Create options for the request
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', //     <-- IMPORTANT
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  })
};

this.http.post(URL, formData, httpOptions).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: node.js server give me error : Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0

Comment: That's probably because you're using `bodyParser.json()` and your API expects a jsno. Try to move the bodyParser.json() line on top of `multer` instantiation

Comment: i can't understand what is wrong... i moved the bodyParser.json() line on top of multer instantiation .. but same error and i reomved bodyParser and the error still appear... i certain that the problem in angular not in node.js code because it is working 100% by postman

Comment: The Angular code I posted is working. Where are you seeing the error then? I removed the JSON stringify line so you cannot get that error anymore on the client.. Also, are you using http or httpClient from Angular?

Comment: I use httpClient in angular

Comment: after i moved the bodyParser.json() line on top of multer it give :  Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0 error...should i user http instead of httpClinet

Answer (score 0):

You need to first instantiate your file in OnInit() before creating an instance in your OnUpload() function which you have done:

```
            ngOnInit() {
this.form = new FormGroup({
  photo: new FormControl(null, {
    validators: [Validators.required]}) }
```

You can remove the validators if you like, you can also edit your onFileSelected() function like this:

```
this.SelectedFile = event.target.files[0] as File;   

this.form.patchValue({ photo: file });
this.form.get('photo').updateValueAndValidity();
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
console.log(file);
```

call your function like this:

```
onUploadFile(event: Event){}
```

Comment: are you mean : reader.readAsDataURL(this.SelectedFile)?... node.js server give me error : Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0

Comment: yes it should be reader.readAsDataURL(this.SelectedFile).....though i don't know if you declare your SelectedFile in your component.ts before using it as you did. if not just declare it as a constant: const selectedFile = event.target.files[0] as File;

Comment: yes i declare SelectedFile in component.ts ... but the problem is after i submit the file,nodejs server give me an error:Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0

Comment: i think your problem is coming from if (!req.file) {
    console.log("No file received");
    return res.send({
      success: false
    }); ..you are sending  a file that is not JSON as a json file.. that is the reason you get "Unexpected Token < in JSON at Position 0".. i will suggest you comment this code "router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));" and try running it or you remove it from that position

Comment: i removed that code and same error still appear...please if you have source code frontend and backend write the code here..I don't know what the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to transfer file to the server, if it's a common scenario, then I will suggest using Dropzone.js angular wrapper. 
Better have a custom angular component with all the custom configuration of Dropzone to meet your needs.

Using it is also quite easy, once you have installed the package, file input is as simple as follow:

```
<dropzone [config]="config" [message]="'Click or drag images here to upload'"

(error)="onUploadError($event)" (success)="onUploadSuccess($event)"></dropzone>
```

Documentation can be found here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dropzone-wrapper